# Cannot use boolean in JSX attribute

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning `React` + `Typescript` and I'm facing a weird problem. Essentially I have defined a `FunctionComponent`:

```
const AddLogModal: React.FC<{ addLog: Function }> = ({ addLog }) => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [attention, setAttention] = useState(false);
    const [tech, setTech] = useState('');
```

and I'm trying to assign to the `checkbox` value the `attention` variable, so I did:

```
 <input
       type="checkbox"
       className="filled-in"
       checked={attention}
       value={attention}
       onChange={e => setAttention(!attention)}
       />
```

so far I get this error:

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The state of the checkbox is set with the `checked` attribute *only* - it doesn't take a `value` as well. Remove this part:

```
value={attention}
```